# Can EE be used together with dynamic serving for mobile?

Tags: mobile

Long overdue, I am looking at trying to make my existing site more mobile-friendly. This was prompted by Google sending out their multi-screen guidelines to Adsense users, but as I went through their basic break-down of possible approaches, I found myself scratching my head quite a bit in terms of how to get this to work with EE.

Since a separate mobile site is out of the question, I am looking at either responsive design or dynamic serving. Since I suspect it would be very tricky to make my current design responsive, dynamic serving would seem like the best bet ... but I can't quite wrap my head around how that would work with EE. The guidelines talk about serving up different templates to different devices, yet somehow serving everything from a single url, but given that templates determine urls in EE that sounds like it could get very complicated? That is, I can see how to do it with the CSS, but not the actual page structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to use a plugin (or create a plugin) to detect whether user is coming from mobile device (via screen size or user-agent sniffing). Such plugin would provide you with conditional statements to use in your templates to render specific view.

Although, I wouldn't recommend this approach, it's an option.

Here's an example plugin:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-mobile-device-detect

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :) I wonder, though, why you feel this is not a good approach?

Comment: In general, the website will become harder to maintain once new features are added/removed. You will have to maintain two sets of templates and two sets of styles (or more). Even though making responsive site via media queries can be time consuming at first (considering current site wasn't build with responsive in mind), over time it will require less time to maintain.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I guess I will see what I can do about converting the current design to being responsive.